# UTF-8 with apache commons-net

Tags: android, utf-8, apache-commons, apache-commons-fileupload

I have problem with Unicode, when I save file in arabic name on sdcard, all things will be good, but when file uploaded to ftp server by commons-net, I will get file name as pic

[image: Bad unicode]

any solution please?

This is a part of code which related with FTPClient:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

                try {

                    FTPClientConfig conf = new FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_NT);
                      conf.setServerLanguageCode("ar");
                      ftpClient.configure(conf);
                    ftpClient.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");
                    ftpClient.setAutodetectUTF8(true); 
                    ftpClient.connect(server, port);
                    ftpClient.login(user, pass);
                    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using filenames in non-latin letters will cause a lot of problems. Many programs will not load or display such files. I would question myself, if there is really a need in this naming of files.